# Change the input type on-focus in JSX doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have a text field which has the placeholder "Dates From". what I wanna do is to change It's input box type to a date type on the focus event. But

but the below mentioned solution doesn't work with JSX.

```
<input placeholder="Date" type="text" onFocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date">
```

How to make this thing work on ReactJs or How to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React changing input type via event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674073/react-changing-input-type-via-event)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using an anonymous function should work, with `e.target`:

```
<input placeholder="Date" type="text" onFocus={(e) => e.target.type = 'date'}  id="date" />
```

You can see it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/km3qv9rjqv).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code     
handleFocus(event) {
        event.target.type = 'date'; 
      }

      render() {
        return (     
            <label>
              Name:
              <input type="text" placeholder="please Enter date"  onFocus={this.handleFocus.bind()} /> 
            </label>

        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a state based approach to this, where you would update the state of the component to track the `type` of the input field when `onFocus` occours by doing something like this:

```
onFocus={ () => this.setState({ typeOfFocused : 'date' }) }
```

Doing this would trigger a re-render which in turn would cause the input element's type to switch to `date` via the following:

```
render() {

     // Extract typeOfFocused from state
     const { typeOfFocused } = this.state

     // Render input type with typeOfFocused if present, or as text by default
     return (<input placeholder="Date" 
             type={ typeOfFocused || 'text' } 
             onFocus={ () => this.setState({ typeOfFocused : 'date' }) } 
             onBlur={ () => this.setState({ typeOfFocused : '' }) }
             id="date">)
 }
```

Here's [a working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/yw45q61prj)